# getView not being called from CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

So I've been lurking around trying to find the answer to this for a while. I'm caving. I need a fresh set of eyes. My View getView inside my CustomAdapter is not being called.

```
public class User_List_Fragment extends ListFragment {
    View view;
    DBHelper db;
    List<UTable> userList;
    ListView list;
    TextView id, firstName, lastName, job;
    String mId;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_users_fragment, container, false);

        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        userList = db.getUserList();

        class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
             private Context context;

            public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<UTable> userList) {
                    super(context, textViewResourceId);
                    this.context = context;
             }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = convertView;
                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, null);
                }

                id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_id);
                firstName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_first_name);
                lastName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_last_name);
                job = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_job);               
                for (UTable uTable : userList) {
                    id.setText(String.valueOf(uTable.getId()));
                    firstName.setText(uTable.getFirstName());
                    lastName.setText(uTable.getLastName());
                    job.setText(uTable.getJob());

                    String mId = String.valueOf(uTable.getId());
                    String mF = uTable.getFirstName();
                    String mL = uTable.getLastName();
                    String j = uTable.getJob();

                    Log.v("ID", mId);
                    Log.v("First Name", mF);
                    Log.v("Last Name", mL);
                    Log.v("Job", j);                    
                 }              
                return row;
            }           
        }
        list.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_row, userList));
        db.close();
        return view; 
    }
}
```

**view_users_fragment.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_data"
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**custom_list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_id" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:text="@string/one"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_first_name" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/first_name_hint"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_last_name" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/last_name_hint"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_job"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="@string/job_hint" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The default `TextView` is instead being called. Which happens when the list is empty and its stating "no data found". I have tested the query to the database and it works. If I place my for loop outside of my getView it returns the results. I think I'm messing up my constructor for my CustomAdapter, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT RE-FACTORED CODE**

**User_List_Fragment.java**

```
public class User_List_Fragment extends ListFragment {
    View view;
    DBHelper db;
    List<UTable> userList;
    ListView list;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_users_fragment, container, false);

        db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        userList = db.getUserList();

        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_row, userList);     
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        db.close();
        return view; 
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UTable> {
     private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<UTable> userList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView== null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_list_row, null);
        }

        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_id);
        TextView firstName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_first_name);
        TextView lastName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_last_name);
        TextView job = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_job);

        UTable uTable = getItem(position);
        if (uTable != null) {
            id.setText(String.valueOf(uTable.getId()));
            firstName.setText(uTable.getFirstName());
            lastName.setText(uTable.getLastName());
            job.setText(uTable.getJob());

            Log.v("JOB", uTable.getJob());
        }
        return convertView;
    }           
}
```

Comment: Ok first an obvious question. You definitely pass in at least one row of data?

Comment: if your referring to userList, yes. If I move my loop outside of getView it returns all the users and their info.

Comment: override getCount method as well

Comment: @yahya don't needed getCount method in `ArrayAdapter`, constructor handle that but i think OP need pass list to constructor too, getCount must be override in `BaseAdapter`

Comment: No. Dont override get count, the array adapter will handle that correctly, unless more than one row is meant to be a single group, in which case you want an expandable list anyway, or no list at all

Comment: @i_me_mine did you see my answer? did you test that?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan I did, it didnt work

Comment: please log `userList.size()` in constructor and tell us the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've just taken a quick look, you are misunderstanding how to use an Adapter.

getView is called by each row of data passed in. Inside get view you should just `getItem(position)` and fill in the fields with that objects data

To be clearer - you wont need a for loop at all, as long as you are extending a baseadapter somewhere in the heirarchy the loop will be automatic

**Example**

```
  class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UTable> {

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<UTable> userList) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, userlist);
         }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView== null) {
               convertView = View.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, null);
            }

            //google the view holder pattern when you are more exerienced
            TextView id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_id);
            TextView firstName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_first_name);
            TextView lastName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_last_name);
            TextView job = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_job);               

            UTable item = getItem(position);
            job.setText(item.getJob());
            ...

            return convertView;
        }           
    }
```

**Things that are broken:**

```
  //Java classes should be named like UserListFragment 
  public class User_List_Fragment extends ListFragment {

     //You shouldnt have these views here, they arent part of the fragmetn
     //they are part of each row in the list and so will keep changing!
     TextView id, firstName, lastName, job;
     String mId;

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       ...

           //You are inside the onCreateView method here - yo ucant decalre a class inside a method!
           class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UTable> {
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, and I am definitely confused on how this is supposed to work. My understanding is that I have a layout with the id/list. That list needs to be filled with my custom_list_row.xml. The way I do that is by implementing a custom adapter. However I do not understand how the getView method works. BaseAdapter is not extended anywhere, only ArrayAdapter<String> on my Custom Adapter. I don't really understand what getItem(position) would accomplish, or where to implement that.

Comment: Alright well your adapter adapts the list of data you pass in, into a list of layouts your listview can display. It does the work in get view() -> each time the list needs to show a row of your data because its been initialised or scrolled, it calls getview with a position, you then write the data from the object in that position, into the layout you defined in xml. The adapter does all the rest of it for you!

Comment: getItem(position) would give you the element in that position of the array you passed in (userlist)

Comment: Oh nice, that makes it much simpler. Still a little confused on how to implement it. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: @NickCardoso getItem and getCount method don't needed in `ArrayAdapter `class, constructor handle all thing, those method used on `BaseAdapter `

Comment: What are you on about Shayan? Clearly you don't know what you are talking about or you have not read this

Comment: @i_me_mine I've added an example - one more thing, ignore my comment about BaseAdapter. It's nothing you need to worry about (basically ArrayAdapter extends a BaseAdapter for you)

Comment: Thanks for the help, It's not working yet, I feel like I'm getting closer though. I edited my post to show you the changes I've made in my code.

Comment: Ok one major problem I missed before - the adapter class cant be declared inside your method! It needs to be the last thing just before your closing } for the class (as an inner class) or even better (and what I recommend) is just put it in its own separate class file

Comment: I've refactored my code. Cleaned it up a bit. Still same problem, getView is not being called.

Comment: Your adapter still thinks it has no data. Change super(context, textViewResourceId); in customadapter to super(context, textViewResourceId, userList);

Comment: By the way, your adapter class looks much better now. Take a look at the comment notes I put on the code at the end of my answer. And also please mark my answer as accepted when/if it's helped you get it working

Comment: Thank you very much for all your time and patience. I really wanted to understand the "why and how" before just copy and pasting a bunch of crap into my project. It works perfectly and now I have something I can use or reference that makes sense to me. I will look up viewHolder as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set CustomAdapter to list view. `list.setAdapter(customAdapter)`

Answer (score 0):

you need pass your data to constructor too, change Constructor method with following code:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<UTable> userList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId , userList);
        this.context = context;
             }
```

or use `BaseAdapter` class instead of `ArrayAdapter` and override GetCount() and GetItem() method and in `GetCount` method return size of your list

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind your getview method is not being called is...

in order to let adapter know how many rows it has, you must pass either your data from Constructor or by overriding the getCount method.

you are not doing any of the thing. so adapter is not aware of any data.

so

use any of this constructor bellow

```
    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T[]%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29
```

or 
override getCount method

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getCount%28%29
```

and you are done.
hope that help